# Getting gawk to output 0 if no arguments available

Tags: bash, scripting, gawk

I am struggling to make this piece of code output 0 if there are no arguments in $5

```
ls -AFl | sed "1 d" | grep [^/]$ | gawk '{ if ($5 =="") sum = 0; else sum += $5 } END { print sum }'
```

When I run this line in a directory without any files in it, it outputs a newline, instead of 0.
I don't understand why? How can I make it so it outputs 0 when there are no files in the directory, any help would be appreciated, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You can change `awk` command to:

```
gawk 'BEGIN { sum = 0 } $5 { sum += $5 } END { print sum }'
```

i.e. initialize `sum` to `0` in `BEGIN` block and aggregate `sum` only when `$5` is non-empty.

Comment: Thank you, I think you meant a curly bracket around the "sum = 0" section though, also, could you explain why my version didn't work? thank you.

Comment: Yes thanks, brace corrected now. `$5==""` doesn't work because when `$5` is blank field 6 becomes field 5.

Comment: ...and this is exactly the kind of reason that you shouldn't parse `ls`!

Comment: Yes I would never recommend parsing `ls` command, I just answered on use of `awk` command. Otherwise as you suggested `stat -c "%s:%F" * | awk -F: '$2=="regular file"{sum+=$1} END{print sum+0}'` is the right way.

Comment: If it worked out, you may mark the answer as accepted by clicking on tick mark on top-left of my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an alternative way of achieving what you want:

```
stat * 2&>/dev/null | awk '/Size/ && !/directory/ { sum += $2 } END { print (sum ? sum : 0) }'
```

This uses awk to parse the output of `stat`. The shell expands the `*` to the names of everything in the current directory. If the directory is empty, `stat` produces an error, which is sent to `/dev/null`.

The awk script adds the value of the second column for lines which contain "Size" but not "directory", so files and symbolic links are included. If you wanted to only count files, you could change `!/directory/` to `/regular file/`.

The ternary operator `? :` means if `sum` is "true", print `sum`, otherwise print `0`. If the directory is empty, `sum` is not defined, so `0` is printed.

As mentioned in the comments, a more concise way of coercing `sum` to a number is to use `print sum+0`, or alternatively using the unary `+` operator `print +sum`. In this case, either are perfectly fine to use, although many recommend against `+sum` in more complex scenarios.

Comment: `print (sum ? sum : 0)` can be code-golfed to `print sum+0`